# something went wrong with your request. please try again later - Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3

I have installed the stripe payment. And after I fill the payment details and try to place the order then I can see this error "something went wrong with your request. please try again later" When I check in admin then order is placed.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs (exception.log,debug.log)

Comment: Yeah, I check the exception log and i can see this error: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for mixins.js

Comment: this error is about file permission issue, the error log does not have writable permission.

Comment: Try to update the permission refer:https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/cannot-ready-contents-mixins-js/td-p/97399

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried out that also but no result.